# Getting Type error as cannot read property undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a user interface for a watch. In this UI if I select a watch of particular color it must be shown in the product preview. But when I select Color of the watch it is giving me error as
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined**.

Can anyone tell me why it is happening. I am giving you code for reference.

```js
//App.js

import logo from './logo.svg';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './App.module.css';
import ProductPreview from './ProductPreview/ProductPreview';
import ProductDetails from './ProductDetails/ProductDetails';
import TopBar from './TopBar/TopBar';
import ProductData from './utils/ProductData';
class  App extends Component {
  state = {
    productData : ProductData,
    currentPreviewImage : "https://imgur.com/Mplj1YR.png",
    showHeartBeatSection: true,
  }

  onColorOptionClick = (pos) => {
    const updatedPreviewImage = this.state.productData.colorOptions[pos].imageUrl;
    console.log(updatedPreviewImage);
    this.setState({currentPreviewImage : updatedPreviewImage});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <TopBar />
        </header>
  
        <div className={classes.MainContainer}>
          <div className={classes.ProductPreview}>
            <ProductPreview currentPreviewImage={this.state.currentPreviewImage} showHeartBeatSection={this.state.showHeartBeatSection} />
          </div>
  
  
          <div className={classes.ProductData}>
            <ProductDetails data={this.state.productData} onColorOptionClick={this.onColorOptionClick} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
    
  

  
}

export default App;
```

```js
//ProductData.js

const ProductData = {
    title: 'FitBit 19 - The Smartest Watch',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor.',
    colorOptions: [
        {
            styleName: 'Black Strap',
            imageUrl: 'https://imgur.com/iOeUBV7.png'
        },
        {
            styleName: 'Red Strap',
            imageUrl: 'https://imgur.com/PTgQlim.png'
        },
        {
            styleName: 'Blue Strap',
            imageUrl: 'https://imgur.com/Mplj1YR.png'
        },
        {
            styleName: 'Purple Strap',
            imageUrl: 'https://imgur.com/xSIK4M8.png'
        },
    ],
    featureList: [
        "Time", "Heart Rate"
    ]
}

Object.freeze(ProductData); //This line of code just makes your object as a constant. No values can be updated.

export default ProductData;
```

```js
//ProductDetails.js

import React from 'react';
import classes from './ProductDetails.module.css';

const ProductDetails = (props) => {
    const colorOptions = props.data.colorOptions.map((item, pos) => {
      const classArr = [classes.ProductImage];
      if(pos === 0) {
        classArr.push(classes.selectedProductImage);
      }
      return(
        <img key={pos} className={classArr.join(' ')} src={item.imageUrl} alt={item.styleName} onClick={() => props.onColorOptionClick()} />
      );
    })

    const featureList = props.data.featureList.map((item, pos) => {
      const classArr = [classes.FeatureItem];
      if(pos === 0){
        classArr.push(classes.SelectedFeatureItem);
      }
      return(
        <button key={pos} className={classArr.join(' ')}>{item}</button>
      )
    })
    return(
        <div className = {classes.ProductData}>
        <h1 className={classes.ProductTitle}>{props.data.title}</h1>
          <p className={classes.ProductDescription}>{props.data.description}</p>

          <h3 className={classes.SectionHeading}>Select Color</h3>
            <div>
              {colorOptions}
             </div>
            <h3 className={classes.SectionHeading}>Features</h3>
            <div> {featureList}</div>
            <button className={classes.PrimaryButton}>Buy Now</button>
        </div>
    );

}

export default ProductDetails;
```

Image of the UI :

[image]

After selecting watch of the color:

[image]

Comment: It means that the value of `item` in `props.data.colorOptions.map((item, pos)` is `undefined` or literally doesn't have value.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot pass `pos` when call `props.onColorOptionClick`. Just update like this:

```
onClick={() => props.onColorOptionClick(pos)} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing position value on the click function to `props.onColorOptionClick` in ProductDetails.js .

```
<img key={pos} className={classArr.join(' ')} src={item.imageUrl} alt={item.styleName} onClick={() => props.onColorOptionClick(pos)} />
```

This should work for you.